# Get vector index positions of based on a condition

Tags: java, algorithm, vector

Let's say I have the vector `vals` and a number `n`:

```
boolean[] vals = new boolean[]{false, true, true, false, false, 
                               true, false, true, true};

int n = 2;
```

I need to define if the vector `vals` has `n` sequential nodes equal to `true`. If it has, then I want to get index positions of these nodes. For instance, in the above-given example, the answer is:

```
{{1,2},{7,8}}
```

Comment: What should be the return value for your example if *all* elements were true?

Comment: You just pose the problem, did you try something to solve it ?

Comment: @aioobe and Klausos, the problem can be reformulated as : find the sequence of _at least_ n consecutive `true` values, and return the (start, end) indexes for each sequence.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have no idea where to begin, and SO isn't really in the business of doing people's homework ... but why don't you begin by describing, in English, step by step, how you would solve the problem. For example, "for each item in the array, I would check if it's true, and then if it is ....."

Comment: So if n=2 and you have 3 or more consecutive true values, do you have to include that subrange or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach.

```
public static int[][] subSeqs(boolean[] vals, int n) {
    List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = -1;
    for (int j = 0; j <= vals.length; j++) {
        boolean b = j == vals.length ? false : vals[j];
        if (b && i == -1) {          // going from false to true
            i = j;
        } else if (!b && i != -1) {  // going from true to false
            if (j-i >= n)
                result.add(new int[] { i, j-1 });
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    return result.toArray(new int[result.size()][]);
}
```

Basically `i` is a "state" variable updated during iteration over the array.

- When `i` is `-1`, we're in a `false` sequence
- When `i` is a non-negative number it represents the index of the first true, in the current true sequence.

So, when we switch from `false` to `true` we set `i` to the current index, and when we switch from `true` to `false` we check if the just-finished `true` sequence was `>= n`.

Comment: Fine, prove me wrong - I just said we didn't do people's homework. Do you really think you're helping the OP?

Comment: As far as I can tell there's absolutely no indication that this is a homework question. I can very easily imagine a this as a real world problem. In fact *today* I was asked to figure out lengths of user sessions, which resembles this problem very well. OP has 1.8k in reputation and I don't think he's on "basic java homework level". None of his previous questions have homework characteristics. I prefer to give people benefit of the doubt in these cases.

Comment: I didn't notice the reputation ... OP showed no indication of having even tried anything, which smells to me like HS or college kid trying to get their work done for them.

Comment: Sometimes when I try to tackle algorithmic problems I sit with pen and paper and fail miserably over and over again. I don't see any value in creating a wall of text describing failed attempts if it's clear that none of those are on the right track. In these cases I personally just write briefly that "I've tried X and Y to no avail", but in the end I see little value in such information when I'm on the answering side.

Comment: @dcsohl: I agree with you if we talk about homework questions. In this particular case, I actually made several "hardcoded" attempts, which has no sense to show here.